# 8051 Timers + Interrupts

Tags: assembly, timer, interrupt, 8051

I am new to working assembly code and I am trying to make a program that will read in values from ROM and depending on what values they are play a certain note for a certain length of time.  The code itself compiles just fine, but when I go to send the code to the 8051, nothing happens.  I think I have the timers setup properly (along with their individual interrupts); however, I am by no means an expert.  And the code doesn't do much right now, it's suppose to just play one note over and over again forever, but nothing happens...  The actual chip is 89LPC932A1 and here is a user manual: http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10109.pdf

Here is the code:

```
#include <reg932.inc>

        NOTE_LENGTH EQU R0
        HIGH_CURRENT_NOTE EQU R1
        LOW_CURRENT_NOTE EQU R2
        TEMP EQU R3
        HIGH_NOTE_LENGTH EQU R4
        LOW_NOTE_LENGTH EQU R5
        DPTR_VALUE EQU R6



        ORG 0
        LJMP SETUP

        ORG 000BH
TIMER0:     CPL P1.7
        MOV TH0, HIGH_CURRENT_NOTE
        MOV TL0, LOW_CURRENT_NOTE
        RETI

        ORG 001BH
TIMER1:     CJNE NOTE_LENGTH, #0, TIMER1_END
        SETB TR0                                
        MOV TEMP, A
        MOV DPTR, #SONG

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV HIGH_CURRENT_NOTE, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV LOW_CURRENT_NOTE, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV NOTE_LENGTH, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV HIGH_NOTE_LENGTH, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV LOW_NOTE_LENGTH, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, TEMP
        MOV DPTR_VALUE, #0
        CLR TR0                         
        RETI

TIMER1_END: DEC NOTE_LENGTH
        RETI


        ORG 0080H
SETUP:      MOV DPTR, #SONG
        MOV DPTR_VALUE, #0

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV HIGH_CURRENT_NOTE, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV LOW_CURRENT_NOTE, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV NOTE_LENGTH, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV HIGH_NOTE_LENGTH, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV A, DPTR_VALUE
        MOVC A, @A+DPTR
        MOV LOW_NOTE_LENGTH, A
        INC DPTR_VALUE

        MOV IEN0, #0x88
        MOV TMOD, #0x11
        SETB TR1
        SETB TR0

MAIN:       SJMP $

        ORG 0F00H
SONG:       DB  80H, 80H, 26, 0, 0

        END
```

Comment: Comments are required in assembly code whenever you expect somebody else to look at it.  SO is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you linked (thanks!) setting `IEN0` to `0x88` only sets `EA` (global interrupt enable) and `ET1` (timer1). So timer0 interrupt is not enabled, hence your `TIMER0` handler will never be invoked. I'd try with `0x8a` instead.

There may very well be other errors, this is just the first one I spotted. You'd better learn to use a debugger or simulator to trace through your program.